# CreativeCommons licence

Tags: legal, licenses, photo, flickr

I want to use some pictures that are published unter the CC Attribution 2.0 Generic licence:
https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/
The licence says that I have to provide a link to this licence and that I must give appropriate credit.

But where and how should I provide this things on my website?
Do you have experience with this kind of "problem"?

Answer (score 2):

On any page that uses the content licensed under the CC Attribution 2.0 Generic licence must contain the link to that license and the appropriate credit. If you use a lot of content under this license you might find it easier to put the link to the license on every page, most likely in a footer. But the attribution must be specific for each piece of content so unless it, too, it common to every page that will probably have to be specific to each page.